# Regular expression validator for password matching multiple rules

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm  trying to create a right regular expression for the RegularExpressionValidator control that allows password to be checked for the following rules: - At least one upper case letter, at least one lower case letter and one special symbol.

How i need to write it in the REV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression should match all the rules you mentioned.

`(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.{8,})(?=.*?[%\$])`

`(?=.*?[a-z])` - This is for ensuring that there is a lowercase character

`(?=.*?[A-Z])` - This is for ensuring that there is an Uppercase character

`(?=.*?[0-9])` - This is for ensuring that there is a digit

`(?=.{8,})`  - For ensuring length of atleast 8 characters

`(?=.*?[%\$)])` - For checking there is atleast one symbol, you will have to give all the symbols you need to be validated. You will also have to ensure to escase right symbols because some of them have special meaning in regular expression.

.*? is to make the regex non greedy.

Comment: thanks..its contains the symbol?

Comment: sorry missed it earlier. Added it now, but it doesn't work for all symbols, you will have to add what all symbols you want.

Answer (score 1):

here is the code `ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$"`

just go through the link which will demonstrate 
http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Password-Policy-using-Regular-Expressions-and-ASPNet-RegularExpression-Validator.aspx

Comment: just visit the link its shows demonstraton

Comment: but this is for at least 8 chars? no?

Comment: yes if u dont want then you can remove {8,} and add any digit you want

Answer (score 1):

I think you does not need regular expression. Just loop through your string and check your `Uppercase`, `Lowercase` and `Special Symbol` exist or not.